# htaccess and hash hiding

Tags: jquery, .htaccess, hash

Afternoon,

Is it possible to put a rule in the htacces redirection something like http://example.com/portfolio to http://example.com/index.php#portfolio while not displaying this last address in the URL field of the browser?

I know the hast doesn't get send to the server, but there must be some kind of way to mask these ugly URLs..

Might be relevant to the question or not, but I have the following jQuery code

```
if(history.pushState){
    history.pushState(null,null,'#'+$(this).attr('class'));
}else{
    location.hash = '#'+$(this).attr('class');}
}

if(window.location.hash){
    var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1);
    if(jQuery.browser.webkit){
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$('#'+hash).offset().top-2*88},'slow');
    }else{
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $('#'+hash).offset().top-3*88-10},'slow');}
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I know the hast doesn't get send to the server, but there must be some kind of way to mask these ugly URLs..

There isn't. By "masking it from the browser", that means the browser has no idea that the URL that it requested has been mangled on the server's end. It thinks it has requested `http://example.com/portfolio` and thus that's what it displays in its address bar.

If you want to **hide** the `#portfolio` fragment from the browser, then the fragment becomes completely useless. The browser, the only entity between the client and server that can possibly get any use out of such a fragment, doesn't see it because the server is hiding it. The server, who has zero use for the fragment, is hiding it from the browser. You can't make the browser load a URL that's different from the one that displays on the address bar without some sort of frame (which hides the URL) or some javascript trickery to change what's in the address bar.

If the server internally rewrites `/portfolio` to `/index.php#portfolio`, the fragment is discarded instantly. The execution of index.php doesn't know it exists because only the browser cares about the fragment.

If you don't want fragments in your URLs, you should rework how your content is being delivered.

Comment: I suspected that ... but is it possible to take the # out of the hash and consider everything after the first slash an hash ?

Comment: @AfonsoGomes It depends on the scripts on the browser's side work. I don't know much about jQuery but you can try changing the code above to check everything after the first slash. Fragments are what different scripts running at the same time on a page communicate with each other so it may break something else on your page.